# Consul:Cannot list event with tag

Tags: events, consul

If I fire event with a tag and service, I cannot list the events

```
PUT  http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/event/fire/eee?tag=t&&service=abc
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "ask":"how much"
}
```

It's ok:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Consul-Default-Acl-Policy: allow
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 12:28:13 GMT
Content-Length: 247
Connection: close

{
  "ID": "d1b228a8-8d04-d837-c0d0-6b853ec6e7e9",
  "Name": "eee",
  "Payload": "ew0KICAgICJhc2siOiJob3cgbXVjaCINCn0NCg0KDQoNCg0KR0VUIGh0dHA6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODUwMC92MS9ldmVudC9saXN0",
  "NodeFilter": "",
  "ServiceFilter": "abc",
  "TagFilter": "t",
  "Version": 1,
  "LTime": 0
}
```

However I cannot list the event.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/event/list
```

It returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Consul-Default-Acl-Policy: allow
X-Consul-Index: 1
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 12:23:29 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Connection: close

[]
```

If I fire event without tag and service, everything will be ok. So i want to know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and found the answer, the service must be registered with the same tag, otherwise the event will not generate, and the list query returns empty later.